# How to get records of table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

- If i choose to show all notes then all notes should be fetched
- If i choose to fetch latest note then latest should be fetched

I need to combine queries; now I have two separate queries for both latest and all notes.

- Latest notes:

  ```
  select notes from activity_notes 
  where id=1 
    and  date=(select max(date) from activity_notes where id=1);
  ```
- All notes is simple:

  ```
  select notes from activity_notes where id =1;
  ```

What should i use to combine them with condition? Should I use a bind variable or `case when` or both? Please help me with solution.

Comment: Why use sub-queries which can be replaced by `order by`?

Comment: Maybe try something like `select notes from activity_notes 
where id=1 
order by date asc limit 1;`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Within a subquery, using `rank` analytic function, compute the highest ranked - in your case, the latest - note. Then pass the parameter which will decide what you want to get as a result.

Something like this:

```
with temp as
  (select notes,
          rank() over (partition by id order by date_column desc) rn
   from activity_notes
  )
select notes
from temp
where id = :par_id
  and rn = case when :par_what = 'ALL' then rn
                when :par_what = 'LATEST' then 1
           end;
```

Comment: Yes something like this only